# Multicolumns in combobox -- make same widths

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am creating a DataGridTemplateColumn with a TextBlock in the CellTemplate, and ComboBox in the CellEditingTemplate.  I am creating all this via FrameworkElementFactory.
For the CellEditingTemplate, I start with a Grid and add a column for each property that needs to be displayed.
Each column contains a Border control containing a TextBlock control; HorizontalAlignment for all controls is set to 'Stretch'.
On the Grid, the IsSharedSizeScopeProperty is set to 'true':

```
FrameworkElementFactory gf = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));
gf.SetValue(Grid.IsSharedSizeScopeProperty, true);
```

For each column, the SharedSizeGroup property is set:

```
  var colDef = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ColumnDefinition));
  colDef.SetValue(ColumnDefinition.SharedSizeGroupProperty, Convert.ToChar(65 + i).ToString());
```

Unfortunately, the display of the right-most column is ragged:
[image]
How can I make each column the same size on every row?  (I thought that's what the SharedSizeGroup property did.)
Thanks for any tips --

Comment: What's the i in Convert.ToChar(65 + i).ToString()?

Comment: @Joe -- an int.  I wanted a simple way to name the SharedSizeGroup, when I didn't know how many columns there would be.